# Session not storing variable

Tags: php, session

My problem is that when calling a static method which contains a switch control, the $_SESSION variable is not stored. Here's my code:

```
class Booking {

static public function bookCourse() {        
$smarty = SmartySingleton::getInstance();
session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['step'])) {
        switch ($_POST['step']) {
            //step 1 post
            case 1:
                //validate                     
                $errors = $validator->validateStep1();                    
                if ($errors == ""){
                    $_SESSION['step1'] = 'test';
                    var_dump($_SESSION); //here it prints test
                    $smarty->display('step2.tpl');
                }else{
                    $smarty->assign('errors', $errors);
                    $smarty->display('step1.tpl');
                }
                break;
            //step 2 post
            case 2:                    
                $errors = $validator->validateStep2();
                if ($errors == ""){
                    var_dump($_SESSION); //here it prints empty array
                    $_SESSION['step2'] = $_POST;   
                    $smarty->display('step3.tpl');
                }else{
                    $smarty->assign('errors', $errors);
                    $smarty->display('step2.tpl');
                }
                break;

           ....
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem? Thank you!

Comment: What exactly happens? Are you 1000% sure the line with the assignment is even reached?

Comment: Are you sure you don't send ANY output to the browser before calling this static function? Just asking because `session_start()` should be called before sending any other output... Turning on logging and checking the logs could help to see if this is the case (you'll get a "headers already sent" error message).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to start your session with the `session_start()` command.

cf: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Note: session_start() should occur as early as possible in your script. As soon as something is printed out it will no longer work.

Comment: Thank youuu!  That was it! Started the session earlier in my code and worked. You saved me! :)

Answer (score 0):

In case 1 , you have assigned `$_SESSION['step1'] = 'test';` so it prints test. Whereas in case 2 , Nothing is assigned.

Comment: But shouldn't it print 'test' from the last step? since session data should remain. I need to be able to save the data assigned in step 1 to access later.

Comment: Have you tried moving session_start() at the very top of your PHP code ?